# spark java how to select newly added column using withcolumn

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create java spark program and trying to add anew column using

```
qdf.withColumn("newColumn", functions.lit("newCOlumn_val"))
```

and when I am trying to select with

```
qdf.withColumn("newColumn", functions.lit("newColumn_val")).select(qdf.col("xyz"),qdf.col("newColumn")).show();
```

its saying ***Cannot reslove column name newColumn***. Can some one please help me how to do this in **Java**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qdf is the dataframe before you added the `newColumn` which is why you are unable to select it with `qdf.col("newColumn")`.

To get a handle on it you can use `functions.col("newColumn")` e.g.

```
qdf.withColumn("newColumn", functions.lit("newColumn_val"))
    .select(functions.col("xyz"),functions.col("newColumn"))
    .show();
```

Alternatively you can store the dataframe after calling `withColumn` and it should then be accessible e.g.

```java
final var qdf2 = qdf.withColumn("newColumn", functions.lit("newColumn_val"));

qdf2.select(qdf2.col("xyz"), qdf2.col("newColumn")).show();
```

Or you can use raw strings as in Srinivas's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
qdf.withColumn("newColumn", functions.lit("newColumn_val"))
.select("xyz","newColumn")
.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use withColumn at all.(Actually it has a very small performance hit over using select directly.)
Just reference the `lit` in the select statement.

```
qdf.select( 
  qdf.col("xyz"), 
  functions.lit("newColumn_val").alias("new Column") 
).show();
```